# How can I use getwd to create a list with the different files that I have in different directories?

Tags: r

I've got 3 directories (testall, testid, testnoid) with different files with the extension .mgf. What I'd like to do is count how many files are in each directory.

To do this I was trying to use this code:

```
file1 <- list.files(file.path(getwd(), "testall", pattern = "\\.mgf$"))

file2 <- list.files(file.path(getwd(), "testid", pattern = "\\.mgf$"))

file3 <- list.files(file.path(getwd(), "testunid", pattern = "\\.mgf$"))
```

`$` at the end means that this is end of string. `"mgf$"` will work too, but adding `\\.` (`.` is special character in regular expressions so you need to escape it) ensure that you match only files with extension `.mgf` (in case I have e.g. .amgf files).

And then use `length(file1)`, `length(file2)`, `length(file3)`

But unfortunately, this doesn't work.

Comment: At the moment, this cannot work simply because you're missing a closing parenthesis in each line.

Comment: In your example, there is a `)` before `, pattern = `. If you missed it in your real case, it is why it is not working. 
Close `file.path` function and `pattern` belongs to `list.files` function

Comment: It should be `list.files(file.path(getwd(), "testall"), pattern = "\\.mgf$")`

Comment: @Titolondon Yes... Its true. I cannot believe that it's this trifle.. Thank you.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thank you. that works. I wasted all morning trying to fix this trifle... This is shameful

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a function?

```
numFiles <- function(x, y){
      length(grep(y, list.files(x)))
}

numFiles("/dir/testall", "\\.mgf")
numFiles("/dir/testid", "\\.mgf")
numFiles("/dir/testunid", "\\.mgf")
```

Just repeat for whichever directory or extension you want.